# What video codecs work on Google Chromebook

Tags: video, ffmpeg, mp4, chromebook

I'm trying to put a show on my friends Google Chromebook but the mp4 files show up black when trying to watch them on said Chromebook, audio works fine. I found out that it is a video encoding problem but I cannot find a list of video formats that work on the Chromebook. I have ffmpeg and handbrake to try and test some things, but if someone could tell me a ffmpeg code that will convert the video files into a format that works on a Google Chromebook that would help a lot.

What I've tried:

```
ffmpeg -i "Game of Thrones S02E01 The North Remembers.mkv" codec mpeg "Game of Thrones S02E01 The North Remembers.mp4"
```

Which gives error:

> [NULL @ 00000177196ea500] Unable to find a suitable output format for
>   'codec' codec: Invalid argument

Comment: Did you encode the videos?

Comment: I did not encode the videos myself, all I did was convert them from mkv to mp4. They are currently encoded in x264

Comment: Show the command and the complete log.

Comment: the ffmpeg I am using right now is {ffmpeg -i "video.mkv" vcodec format "video.mp4"} Not sure what goes inbetween the two strings. I'm pretty sure that's where I put the encoder I want.

Comment: I need to see the actual command and the complete log from the command.

Comment: ffmpeg -i "Game of Thrones S02E01 The North Remembers.mkv" codec mpeg "Game of Thrones S02E01 The North Remembers.mp4"                                          [NULL @ 00000177196ea500] Unable to find a suitable output format for 'codec'
codec: Invalid argument I don't really need help with the syntax, I just want to know what type of encoded video files work on a Google Chromebook

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1V14W0qsQaF5dsMWs5Jfkw2jrba00cxoa/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Seems like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me, but to answer your question see [File types and external devices that work on Chromebooks](https://support.google.com/chromebook/answer/183093?hl=en). As for your file it's 10-bit HEVC/H.265 which is not listed in the not-very-detailed table in the link I provided. You can try re-muxing to MP4: `ffmpeg -i input.mkv -c copy output.mp4`. Not sure if that will work. Or re-encode: `ffmpeg -i input.mkv -c:v libx264 -vf format=yuv420p -profile:v main -c:a copy -movflags +faststart output.mp4`.

Answer (score 0):

(1) Try [VLC for Chrome OS](https://www.videolan.org/vlc/download-chromeos.html) because its powered by FFmpeg anyway, so maybe its own code will actually display the stream directly from the MKV file without even a need to convert.

(2) To avoid error, you must set codec by `-c:v mpeg` not by `codec mpeg`.
Some Ffmpeg versions don't know `-c:v` option so use `-vcodec` instead.

If you have an H265 (HEVC) video then I suggest you re-encode to H264 (AVC) to allow playback on more devices. See **@llogan**'s comments under your question

Try as:

```
ffmpeg -i "Game of Thrones S02E01 The North Remembers.mkv" -c:v libx264 -vf format=yuv420p -profile:v main -c:a copy -movflags +faststart "Game of Thrones S02E01 The North Remembers.mp4"
```

Comment: If a build does not support `-c:v` it's way too old to be worth using.